# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException for Scala Design Patterns

Tags: scala, design-patterns, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

This is a weird issue I'm facing with Scala Design Patterns.

Here's my sample code

```
trait ReportFactory
object ReportFactory {  
    def apply(reportType : String) = reportType match {
    case "RepA" => new ClassRepA(repDF) 
    case "RepB" => new ClassRepA(repDF)         
    }
}
```

calling it as

```
def executeReports(reportType : String) = reportType match {
        case "RepA" =>  ReportFactory("RepA")
        case "RepB" => ReportFactory("RepB")            
        }
```

Class Definitions

```
ClassRepA(reportName : String) extends Serializable with ReportFactory {
//use Dataframe for processing Reports A
}  

ClassRepB(reportName : String) extends Serializable with ReportFactory {
//use Dataframe for processing Report B
}
```

Issue :
When RepB is executes, I get

> java.lang.InstantiationException: com.xxx.ClassRepB

I also see

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   ccom.xxx.ClassRepB.()   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)   ... 40 more

What am I doing here ??
I generate a DataFrame.. cache it.. and then pass the same DataFrame to subsequent reports depending on the business logic of each Report.

I have tried a log of workarounds like `def this() {this()}` but nothing seems to be working.
I'm not sure why this error. If anybody has an idea/ suggestions, please let me know , I will try it out.

**EDIT:**

My bad..

Here's the edited snippet..

```
trait ReportFactory
object ReportFactory {  
        def apply(repDF: Dataframe, reportType : String) = reportType match {
        case "RepA" => new ClassRepA(repDF) 
        case "RepB" => new ClassRepA(repDF)         
        }
    }
```

repDF is created in another package and then it is passed to these Classes,

Comment: where is your `repDF` coming from in the apply method?

Comment: Are you doing all that dataframe creation etc in `constructor` of `ClassRepA` or `ClassRepB` ??

Comment: Its not clear to me, are these ClassRepA/B case clases or normal Scala classes? Are they objects (singletons)?

Comment: Thanks all.. I have edited the snippet.. @leshkin : they are normal Scala classes.. I have 5-6 case classes within Class A and Class B